# Delphi: At runtime find classes that descend from a given base class?

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-5

Is there at way, at runtime, to find all classes that descend from a particular base class?

For example, pretend there is a class:

```
TLocalization = class(TObject)
...
public
   function GetLanguageName: string;
end;
```

or pretend there is a class:

```
TTestCase = class(TObject)
...
public
   procedure Run; virtual;
end;
```

or pretend there is a class:

```
TPlugIn = class(TObject)
...
public
   procedure Execute; virtual;
end;
```

or pretend there is a class:

```
TTheClassImInterestedIn = class(TObject)
...
public
   procedure Something;
end;
```

At runtime i want to find all classes that descend from `TTestCase` so that i may do stuff with them.

Can the RTTI be queried for such information?

**Alternatively:** Is there a way in Delphi to walk every class? i can then simply call:

```
RunClass: TClass;

if (RunClass is TTestCase) then
begin
   TTestCase(RunClass).Something;
end;
```

### See also

- [Finding all classes that derive from a given base class in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986335/finding-all-classes-that-derive-from-a-given-base-class-in-python)
- [Java: At runtime, find all classes in app that extend a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205573/java-at-runtime-find-all-classes-in-app-that-extend-a-base-class)

Comment: the question could be on how to enumerate all objects owned by an application

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo i could phrase the question a number of ways. Hopefully one of the phrasings will give me a solution.

Comment: If the example you provided has some bearing on why you want to use it, ie you are mainly interested in all DUnit testcase classes, you could of course simply "walk" the RegisteredTests registry that DUnit itself builds up to run all the tests. I now see your TTestCase descends from TObject - and probably does not have a relation to DUnit, so forget my comment. I'd delete it if SO would let me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, yes, there is a way, but you're not going to like it. (Appearantly, I need a disclaimer like this, to prevent my otherwise perfectly helpfull comment getting downvoted by the oh-so knowledgable, but not so forgiving 'senior' SO members.)

FYI : The following description is a high-level overview of a piece of code I actually wrote when Delphi 5 was the latest & greatest. Since then, that code was ported over to newer Delphi versions (currently up until Delphi 2010) and still works!

For starters, you need to know that a class is nothing more than a combination of a VMT and the accompanying functions (and maybe some type-info, depending on compiler-version and -settings). As you probably know, a class - as identified by the type TClass - is just a pointer to the memory address of that classes' VMT. In other words : If you known the address of the VMT of a class, that's the TClass pointer as well.

With that piece of knowledge stuck firmly in your mind, you can actually *scan* your executable memory, and for each address test if it 'looks like' a VMT. All addresses that seem to be a VMT can than be added to a list, resulting in a complete overview of all classes contained in your executable! (Actually, this even gives you access to classes declared solely in the implementation-section of a unit, and classes linked-in from components & libraries that are distributed as binaries!)

Sure, there's a risk that some addresses seem to be a valid VMT, but are actually some random other data (or code) - but with the tests I've come up with, this has never happened to me yet (in about 6 years running this code in more than ten actively maintained applications).

So here's the checks you should do (in this exact order!) :

1. Is the address equal to the address of TObject? If so, this address is a VMT and we're done!
2. Read TClass(address).ClassInfo; If it's assigned :

   1. it should fall inside a code-segment (no, I won't go into details on that - just google it up)
   2. the last byte of this ClassInfo (determined by adding SizeOf(TTypeInfo) + SizeOf(TTypeData)) should also fall inside that code-segment
   3. this ClassInfo (which is of type PTypeInfo) should have it's Kind field set to tkClass
   4. Call GetTypeData on this ClassInfo, resulting in a PTypeData

      1. This should also fall inside a valid code segment
      2. It's last byte (determined by adding SizeOf(TTypeData)) should also fall inside that code-segment
      3. Of this TypeData it's ClassType field should be equal to the address being tested.
3. Now read the VMT-to-be at the offset vmtSelfPtr and test if this results in the address being tested (should point to itself)
4. Read vmtClassName and check if that points to a valid classname (check pointer to reside in a valid segment again, that the string length is acceptable, and IsValidIdent should return True)
5. Read vmtParent - it should also fall in a valid code segment
6. Now cast to a TClass and read ClassParent - it should also fall in a valid code segment
7. Read vmtInstanceSize, it should be >= TObject.InstanceSize and <= MAX_INSTANCE_SIZE (yours to determine)
8. Read vmtInstanceSize from it's ClassParent, it should also be >= TObject.InstanceSize and <= the previously read instance size (parent classes can never be larger than child classes)
9. Optionally, you could check if all VMT entries from index 0 and upwards are valid code pointers (although it's a bit problematic to determine the number of entries in a VMT... there's no indicator for this).
10. Recurse these checks with the ClassParent. (This should reach the TObject test above, or fail miserably!)

If all these checks hold, the test-address is a valid VMT (as far as I'm concerned) and can be added to the list.

Good luck implementing this all, it took me about a week to get this right.

Please tell how it works out for you. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting approach, but isn't it risky and a complex solution when something like creating your own class registry would achieve the same thing in a safer manner?

Comment: @David: No, they are nowhere near equivalent. With your own registry, you are always limited to the classes you actively register. With Patrick's approach you can detect **all** classes present in your exe... No RTTI or registry required. And in D2010+ no RTTI is an advantage as it helps avoid code bloat of the exe.

Comment: You're right: i'm not going to like it :)  But accepted as the (only) answer. +1 for being ingenious +1 for a thorough explanation

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with RTTI, but not in Delphi 5.  In order to find all classes that match a certain criteria, you first need to be able to *find all classes*, and the RTTI APIs necessary to do that were introduced in Delphi 2010.  You'd do it something like this:

```
function FindAllDescendantsOf(basetype: TClass): TList<TClass>;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  lType: TRttiType;
begin
  result := TList<TClass>.Create;
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  for lType in ctx.GetTypes do
    if (lType is TRttiInstanceType) and
       (TRttiInstanceType(lType).MetaclassType.InheritsFrom(basetype)) then
      result.add(TRttiInstanceType(lType).MetaclassType);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ian, as Mason says the [`TRttiContext.GetTypes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TRttiContext.GetTypes) function get the list of all RTTI objects  that provide type information . but this function was introduced in Delphi 2010.

As workaround you can inherit your base class from the [`TPersistent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TPersistent) class and then register manually every class using the [`RegisterClass`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.RegisterClass) function (i know wich this is annoying).

then using the [`TClassFinder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TClassFinder) object you can retrieve all the registered classes.

see this sample

```
type
  TForm12 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo; // a TMemo to show the classes in this example
    ButtonInhertisFrom: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonInhertisFromClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    RegisteredClasses : TStrings; //The list of classes
    procedure GetClasses(AClass: TPersistentClass); //a call procedure used by TClassFinder.GetClasses
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TTestCase = class (TPersistent) //Here is your base class 
  end;

  TTestCaseChild1 = class (TTestCase) //a child class , can be in any place in your application
  end;

  TTestCaseChild2 = class (TTestCase)//another child class
  end;

  TTestCaseChild3 = class (TTestCase)// and another child class
  end;

var
  Form12: TForm12;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

//Function to determine if a class Inherits directly from another given class
function InheritsFromExt(Instance: TPersistentClass;AClassName: string): Boolean; 
var
  DummyClass : TClass;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Assigned(Instance) then
  begin
    DummyClass := Instance.ClassParent;
    while DummyClass <> nil do
    begin
      if SameText(DummyClass.ClassName,AClassName) then
      begin
        Result := True;
        Break;
      end;
      DummyClass := DummyClass.ClassParent;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm12.ButtonInhertisFromClick(Sender: TObject);
var
Finder       : TClassFinder;
i            : Integer;
begin
  Finder     := TClassFinder.Create();
  try
   RegisteredClasses.Clear; //Clear the list
   Finder.GetClasses(GetClasses);//Get all registered classes
   for i := 0 to RegisteredClasses.Count-1 do
     //check if inherits directly from TTestCase
     if InheritsFromExt(TPersistentClass(RegisteredClasses.Objects[i]),'TTestCase') then
     //or you can use , if (TPersistentClass(RegisteredClasses.Objects[i]).ClassName<>'TTestCase') and  (TPersistentClass(RegisteredClasses.Objects[i]).InheritsFrom(TTestCase)) then //to check if a  class derive from TTestCase not only directly
     Memo1.Lines.Add(RegisteredClasses[i]); //add the classes to the Memo 
  finally
  Finder.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm12.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisteredClasses := TStringList.Create;
end;

procedure TForm12.GetClasses(AClass: TPersistentClass);//The cllaback function to fill the list of classes
begin
  RegisteredClasses.AddObject(AClass.ClassName,TObject(AClass));
end;


initialization
//Now the important part, register the classes, you can do this in any place in your app , i choose this location just for the example
  RegisterClass(TTestCase);
  RegisterClass(TTestCaseChild1);
  RegisterClass(TTestCaseChild2);
  RegisterClass(TTestCaseChild3);
end.
```

**UPDATE**

I'm sorry, but apparently the `TClassFinder` class was introduced in Delphi 6

Comment: But your idea is still valid. Instead of registering the classes with a registry provided by Delphi, he would just have to create a registry with the appropriate methods himself. It ain't that hard... Plus it has the advantage that he doesn't have to require all "discoverable" classes to descend from TPersistent. TObject will do nicely.

Comment: @Marjan Venema i would do that, but i'm asking the question so i can avoid needing an initialization section.

Comment: @Ian: You wouldn't need initialization sections if you were to use a separate "registration" unit. It would have to reference the unit defining the registry and each and every unit containing a class that you want registered. Advantage: no initialization sections, all registered classes in one place and easier to spot units no longer used. Disadvantage: this unit would need to change every time you add a class that needs to be registered.